# XQUERY: Querying the output of query multiple times with different parameters

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a lot of XML files and I need to output the file names based on user-defined input from the command line.

Here is a simple example of XQuery which captures the essence of the problem.

File1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Description>  
  <FileName>File1</FileName>
  <Persons>
    <Person>
      <Name>Anna</Name>
      <Age>25</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Marco</Name>
      <Age>25</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Mary</Name>
      <Age>13</Age>
    </Person>
  </Persons>
</Description>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Description>
  <FileName>File2</FileName>
  <Persons>
    <Person>
      <Name>Anna</Name>
      <Age>25</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Marco</Name>
      <Age>11</Age>
    </Person>
  </Persons>
</Description>
```

For example, the user needs to get the name of the file which contains persons: Anna of age 25 and Marco of age 25.
I wrote a dirty solution.
I am wondering if it can be done in generic form for an arbitrary number of input pairs (Name, Age).

Here, the inputs are hardcoded in search.xq.

search.xq

```
(: person and age are user defined inputs of arbitrary length :)
let $person:= ('Anna', 'Marco')
let $age:= (25, 25)

(: Output needs to be name of file which have person (Anna, 25) and (Marco,25):)
return collection('db')/Description/Persons/Person[(Name=$person[1] and Age=$age[1])]/../Person[(Name=$person[2] and Age=$age[2])]/../../FileName
```

output:

```
<FileName>File1</FileName>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (which assumes that your XQuery processor allows you to pass on maps as user-defined input):

```
declare variable external $INPUT := map {
  'Anna': 25,
  'Marco': 25
};

for $description in collection('db')/Description
where every $test in map:for-each($INPUT, function($name, $age) {
  exists($description/Persons/Person[Name = $name and Age = $age])
}) satisfies $test
return $description/FileName
```

The second alternative is closer to your original solution. Names and ages are bound to separate variables:

```
declare variable $NAMES external := ('Anna', 'Marco');
declare variable $AGES external := (25, 25);

for $description in collection('db')/Description
where every $test in for-each-pair($NAMES, $AGES, function($name, $age) {
  exists($description/Persons/Person[Name = $name and Age = $age])
}) satisfies $test
return $description/FileName
```

Comment: Thank you! I have only one problem, in a real case, I have 6 variables, not 2 like in this case with name and age.

Comment: I think the idea will be exactly the same.

Comment: I have learned a lot from your answer , thank you once again.